# ios keyboard not resizing the view

Tags: ios, flutter

while `ios` `softkeyboard` rises, contents of the screen not getting resized. Or can't scroll the view to the extend that lower contents of the screen is not accessible. ie, lower part of the screen will always be obscured by the soft keyboard

tried:

1. using `resizeToAvoidBottomInsets` both true and false,
2. using `SizedBox` at the bottom of the screen with height `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`
3. using older and newer flutter sdk versions
   working as expected in android but not in `ios`.
   Seems like `ios` keyboard is not detected by flutter

Comment: it turns out that the problem occurs only for the screen having things that dont scroll, like bottombar or custom appbar